# How to write data to excel columnwise

Tags: java

I need to write data to excel from a list columnwise. For example(Person name and age):
Person1    Person2
20         30

With the below code it gets printed rowwise  :
Person1 20
Person2 30

```
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Person details");
        for(int i = 0; i < personList.size(); i++){
            XSSFRow xssfRow = sheet.createRow(i);
            xssfRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(personList.get(i).getName());
            xssfRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(personList.get(i).getAge());
        }
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a class `PersonDetails` for each row and edit each element of the class? 
This way, you can logically "edit" each object columnwise.

Afterwards, you iterate over the elements and write each of them in you excel document"